# How do you open encrypted OOXML document in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, ole, openxml

I want to open encrypted OOXML files, which are stored as streams inside a compound OLE file.  Microsoft has an API for OOXML, ([OOXML Format SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx)), but it seems to lack a way to manipulate encrypted OOXML documents.  So, this breaks into two questions.

- How do you open compound OLE documents in C#?  I found this very similar question, ([reading compound documents in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179128/reading-compound-documents-in-c)), but I was hoping that there might be a cleaner and more generic way of doing it that I missed.
- Is there a high-level way to decrypt the `EncryptedPackage` stream within the OLE document?  The two best references I've found are [Decrypting Office Documents](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=35) and [MS-OFFCRYPTO Examples](http://www.codeplex.com/offcrypto).  "Decrypting Office Documents" seems to decrypt successfully, but it relies on an external DLL (*Lyquidity.OleStorage.dll*) to open the OLE document and did not work for me.  "MS-OFFCRYPTO Examples" has an example in C# to decrypt the stream but uses a C++ example to get the stream.  Both these references look like they work, but is there a higher level API that does the same thing?

Comment: Similar question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502781/read-write-excel-2007-password-protected-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no there is no higher level API.
Long answer: the [MS-OFFCRYPTO Examples](http://www.codeplex.com/offcrypto) is the best example of how to decrypt it, but you will have to use a library (or make your own) for interacting with the OLE document. There are many libraries for [OLE Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage) such as [OpenMCDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openmcdf/) and the library from [GemBox Software](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/CompoundFile.htm)